# IE PDF iframe onload event issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, pdf, iframe

I have an iframe which loads with pdf document, I need to a show spinner (loading) message to the user while it is loading. I can show the spinner on-load of the page but I am having an issue to hide the spinner in IE browser, IE iframe does not fire the event for PDF document, other browsers working just fine.

```
<iframe id="pdfFrame" onload="hideSpinner()" src="CompensationStatement.pdf" width="100%" height="50%"> </iframe>
```

Comment: Is IE displaying the PDF using the Adobe Reader plugin?

Comment: Yes, IE uses Adobe plugin

Comment: Once IE has passed control of loading the PDF to the Reader plug-in, it no longer gets any messages. My suggestion would be to remove the src attribute from your iframe element and load the PDF via AJAX, when it's complete, then set the src attribute to the PDF blob.